# Can you refresh an onload function/make in iframe resize to the contents as a link changes the page

Tags: iframe, refresh, onload

I'm trying to resize my page to the size of the contents loaded inside of an iframe.

The first page which loads when you visit has a lot of video's in the list and makes the page quite long. However when I load another page into it which is smaller it stays at the bigger size from the previously loaded page, here is my working code:

```
<div class="videoplayer">
    <iframe src="video/index.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="668" name="videoplayer" onload="this.style.height=this.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight +'px';"></iframe>
</div>
```

here are the links in the menu:

```
<p>
    <a href="video/index.html" target="videoplayer">Featured Video's</a> | 
    <a href="video/Anub1s.html" target="videoplayer">Anub1s</a> | 
    <a href="video/Bl4ze.html" target="videoplayer">Bl4ze</a> | 
    <a href="video/DrJ4y.html" target="videoplayer">DrJ4y</a> | 
    <a href="video/Budboy.html" target="videoplayer">Budboy</a> | 
    <a href="video/KillerClay.html" target="videoplayer">Killer Clay</a> | 
    <a href="video/Pewpew.html" target="videoplayer">PewPew</a>
</p>
```

Is there a way I can refresh the onload function so it knows it's been updated?

So I've been trying to do it this way:

The pages above have this code^^

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    parent.iframeLoaded();
}
</script>
```

and this is the content in the main page:

```
<script>
function iframeLoaded() {
    this.style.height=this.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight +'px';
}
</script>
```

With `onload="iframeLoaded();"` in the iframe.. But it's not working

Comment: I've read the related article and don't understand how to send a link and then make it resize still if anyone can help please comment

Comment: ps I;ve tried various javascript ways and they didn't work